# Keras TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to create a model in Keras, on jupyter notebooks which is being run on a digital ocean vpn.
I created it like so:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128,input_shape=(40,105)))
```

However, I am getting the error

`TypeError: Expected int32, got list containing Tensors of type '_Message' instead.`

I am running keras 2.1.2 and tensorflow 1.4.1.
I tried lowering the number of LSTM cells created but that didn't help.
I have no clue why there is a type error.

Perhaps it is the VPN which is causing the problem? It is a very powerful VPN so I don't think it is running out of memory...

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure that TF 1.4.1 is being used?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro When I open the terminal and run python3, import tensorflow as tf, print(tf.__version__), i get 1.4.1, but when I run the same command in my notebook I get 0.12. Any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Well it is clear that you have two TF installations, probably because you also have two python installations. Get rid of one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is caused because you are using a very old TensorFlow version, not 1.4.1 as you stated. You either need to upgrade it, or make sure that the newest version is used.